# Finding The Delta In Properties Between two files

Tags: bash, sed, diff

This is primarily an approach/concept question, and I appreciate any input you might have.

The problem:
I often need to compare and edit a property file, and in doing so I'm mainly interested to find new properties that exist in the new file compared to the old one. To achieve this I often employ `diff old_file.prop new_file.prop`,but due to the high number of lines/properties in each file (~150) this method isn't efficient and is error prone.

Sample `old_file.prop`:

```
name.host=mycomputer1
internal.port=21
external.gateway=sample.my.machine
```

Sample `new_file.prop`:

```
name.host=change_me
internal.port=21
external.gateway=change_me
external.port=501
```

Here `diff` command will return:

```
<name.host=mycomputer1
<external.gateway=sample.my.machine
>name.host=change_me
>externa.gateway=change_me
>external.port=501
```

The only output of interest/desired in this example is `external.port` and not the value it holds (and perhaps a line number as well). I'm a bit familiar with `sed`, but I don't think it can do this without prior knowledge of the properties in the new file.

Is there a way to efficiently achieve this using bash script?

Thank you,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code for GNU [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
awk -F= 'NR==FNR {a[$1]++;next}; !a[$1] {print $1, "line", FNR}' fileOld fileNew
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this returns the property that is the same for both sets/files. I've executed the suggested command and the output is `internal.port line 2` whereas I'm looking for the output `external.port` (and line 4, if possible).

Comment: is there a way to change your command, so it'll only show the properties that exist in one file but not in the other?

Comment: It seems, `not in` doesnt work :(. I will change this soon. :)

Comment: Code fixed, sorry for the delay. Btw. you have a typo in `new_file.prop`, missing `l`  in `externa.gateway`.

Comment: Thank you for the modification, but it actually doesnt run in command line, only in bash script. But that's fine.

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Would be perfect if you could give an explanation of how it works.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative on @mob's answer, and to give some other possibilities:

1. To show properties that have been removed in new_file

   `comm -23 <(cut -d= -f1 old_file) <(cut -d= -f1 new_file)`
2. To show properties that have been added in new_file

   `comm -13 <(cut -d= -f1 old_file) <(cut -d= -f1 new_file)`
3. To show common properties in the two files

   `comm -22 <(cut -d= -f1 old_file) <(cut -d= -f1 new_file)`

Comment: Thank you for providing additional options. 
I think there an issue with my system, I execute the command without any spaces (from left to right) `<(cut` ... `old_file.property)` `<(cut` ... new_file.property)`

Comment: @Simply_Me Make sure you are using `bash` as your shell if you want that to work on the command line. That syntax might work on `zsh` too (not very familiar with that) but it won't work on `ksh`, `sh` or `csh` to name a few others.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `cut` to ignore any input after the first `=` on each line:

```
diff <(cut -d= -f1 old_file) <(cut -d= -f1 new_file)
```

Projected output:

```
22a23
> external.port
```

Comment: Hi @mob ,
Thank you for the, extremely, quick reply!
when executing the command I get `Missing name for redirect.`

Comment: What I've executed, just double checking:

`$ diff < (cut -d= -f1 old_file.property) < (cut -d= -f1 new_file.property)
Missing name for redirect.`

Comment: @Simply_Me Don't put the space between `<` and `(` - type it just like @mob did...

Comment: @twalberg Thank you for the clarification, but I think there is a compatibility issue with my system. I enter the command (as I described in my other comment to you):
`<(cut` ... `old_file.property)` `<(cut ... new_file.property)` 

Not sure how to fix this though. Nonetheless, I appreciate your replies.

Comment: @mob @twalbeg Not sure why, but the following command runs fine from a file but not from the command line. At any rate, I'm happy, thank you for your help and comments.

`diff <(cut -d= -f1 old_file.property) <(cut -d= -f1 new_file.property) | tee -a log1.log`

Comment: @twalberg and mob , thank you for your input; very appreciated. I accepted captcha 's answer though, since it seems most elegant (though I might be wrong b/c I'm not an expert by any means for command line techniques).

Comment: @twalberg , you are correct, I just checked my shell and it's `tcsh`.